# Move Popup Around Screen after Loading Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I'm doing a personal design project and I'm working with automatic pop up windows cluttering your screen. Now I'm trying to make the popup windows dance around your screen but only after they load the content on their windows. 
Reason being is that I'm noticing I can make them move around, but only after they stop moving do they load their content. Is there anyway to reverse this?

To make them popup, I have something like this:

```
var W3 = window.open('oculuspic.html','Popup3',"toolbar=no,status=no,location=yes, left=0, top=320, directories=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=400,height=300");
```

To make them move, something like this:

```
W3.moveTo(0,420); W150.moveTo(0,320); 
W3.moveTo(0,220); W150.moveTo(0,120);   
W3.moveTo(0,0); 
setTimeout('pop()', 1);
```

If there is a better way to make them move also, that'd be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can try couple of approaches:

Approach 1:

```
window.onload = function(){
   //add your move logic
}
```

Approach 2:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //add your move logic here
});
```